# combine multiple excel values from an array back into a single excel cell comma separated

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have multiple values that I'm reading into an array, but I need to paste those values into a single cell comma separated. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you working with a single dimension array?

Answer (score 3):

You can `Join` an array with a given separator

```
myArray = Array("John","Bob","Mary")     
sString = Join(myArray, ",")
msgbox sString
```

Will give you "John,Bob,Mary" in sString...

To put this into a cell:
`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = sString`

Comment: edited to include cell set - just change cell and sheet name to match your own worksheet